# powershell Copy .txt files from different folders based on timestamp and paste it to backup folder of same subfolder

Tags: powershell, copy-paste

How can I copy and paste files from the below structure?

- Source folder - D:\ClientData*\HrPay\Group*\STP
- Destination Folder - D:\ClientData*\HrPay\Group*\STP_BKP

I need to copy all the .txt files from source folders to the destination folder based on timestamp.
If it is a single folder I am able to copy and paste but it has multiple folders and subfolders.

**Source folder**

- D:\ClientData\12\HrPay\Group\grp1\STP
- D:\ClientData\12\HrPay\Group\grp2\STP
- D:\ClientData\13\HrPay\Group\grp1\STP
- D:\ClientData\14\HrPay\Group\grp1\STP
- D:\ClientData\15\HrPay\Group\grp2\STP

Could anyone please guide me on how can I iterate through all these folders and paste it to the same folder with a backup subfolder?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm sure you've already read the help [Ask] and took the [Tour]. If not you should do now, please. Have you tried to search for a solution? There are probably thousands of examples for something basic like your question. Take a look at [robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy).

Comment: yes , but i want to do this by powershell

Comment: So you have to add the word "_Powershell_" to your search phrase. What kind of help do you need? SO is not a free code writing service. We can try to help with code you already wrote and does not work as expected but we will not write it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Copy-Item` then you can use `-Recurse` parameter in order to copy sub folders.

Comment: I am able to recurse but how to create back up of each folder ? Really struggling as ther are multiple folders and inside that multiple sub folders are there
D:\ClientData\13\HrPay\Group\grp1\STP 

How to create back up for each folder D:\ClientData\13\HrPay\Group\grp1\STP_Bkp

Comment: If you copy folder 'D:\ClientData'. It will automatically copy all its sub folders and files. Why you want to create a new structure with '_BKP' suffix.

Comment: i want to copy only some files inside the STP folder based on timestamp and copy that files to a back up folder of same directory with STP_BKP

I have multiple folder with different name .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#Note: Path must be parent of first directory to create a
#      backup for!
$Dirs = Get-ChildItem -path "G:\Test" -Recurse  | 
   Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}  

#--- Create Backup Directories & Copy Files ---
$Dirs | ForEach-Object  {

          $NIArgs = @{Path     = "$($_.FullName)"
                      Name     = "Backup"
                      ItemType = "Directory"}

          Try   { New-Item @NIArgs }
          Catch {} #Directory Exists

          $BkUpDir =  "$($_.FullName)" + "\Backup"

          Get-ChildItem -path "$($_.FullName)"         | 
            Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $False} |
            Copy-Item -Destination "$BkUpDir"

        } #End ForEach-Object
```

Comment: Thank you . This helps . i will update the script accordingly